# Publish app using xCode 9 with deployment target 6.0

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a 2 years old app on App Store that has 6.0 deployment target. But it is not running on iOS 11. Its saying "The developer of this app needs to update it to work with iOS 11".

Now I am using xCode 9 and it gives me error in story board that "Compiling IB documents not supported for earlier than iOS 7 is no longer supported". It got fixed by setting "Builds for" option to iOS 7.

Does it means I cannot release this app for iOS 6.0? How can I make a new release that supports from iOS 6.0 to latest iOS 11?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You should bump the Base SDK to iOS11. You likely can leave the Deployment Target at iOS6.

For Storyboards, click on the Storyboard. Show the Utilities Pane (on the right), and click the first tab (File Inspector). There you can set the "Builds for" setting to higher than iOS6, or whatever you have it set to.

Also, make sure to address any warnings that Xcode tells you about regarding code or project settings, that might pertain to this issue.

Comment: I have set Base SDK to iOS 11. Problem is, there is no option of "iOS 6.0 and later" in "Builds for" setting. Minimum available option is "iOS 7.0 or later" and "Deployment Target (6.0)". If I select "Deployment Target (6.0)", then it gives me error on build "Compiling IB documents for earlier than iOS 7 is no longer supported".

Comment: @BilalAhmad Yeah, you have to use iOS7+ storyboard format in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you must do is add 64-bit architecture (arm64) to the list of valid architectures in target settings. You are not required to build app with Xcode 9, it's still allowed to use Xcode 6 or later.